# StringVar() with Listbox multiple or extended - lists converting to string

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I have a tkinter `Listbox` and I'm using a `StringVar().set()` to set the values from a list. When I get the values back using `StringVar().get()`, they are converted to an awkward string format, like this:

```
"('Item1', 'Item2', 'Item3')"
```

What's the best way to avoid this conversion in the first place, or failing that, to convert the string back to the initial list?

You can use this snippet of code to reproduce the problem in its most simple form:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
values = tk.StringVar(root)
values.set(['Item1', 'Item2','Item3'])
print(values.get())
```

It's not pretty, but I had come up with this:

```
values.get()[2:-2].split("', '")
```

Comment: you could use [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) and the [docs](https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/listbox.html) state that _If you call the .get() method of the listvariable, you will get back a string of the form "('v0', 'v1', ...)", where each vi is the contents of one line of the listbox._ which probably means that there is not really any built-in way to achieve it but rather have to use your own method or `ast.literal_eval`

Comment: also don't use `str` as a variable name, it is a built-in Python function

Comment: I mean it is a `StringVar` (see `String` in its name) so what did you expect, also the pattern doesn't change so using the other method would work too but it just doesn't look as good (also need to account for the extra `'`) and also see comment below which solves this without effort

Comment: Use `tk.Variable` instead of `tk.StringVar`.

Comment: @acw1668 - thank you, that works like a dream. Perhaps write a couple of lines as an answer?

Comment: I realize this is an old question, but where's the Listbox? If you assign your `tk.StringVar` variable to the `listvariable=` argument Tkinter does the rest for you. Of course type checking gets confused, but... details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As `StringVar` is inherited from `Variable` with overridden `get()` function which converts the stored value to `string`.

Using `Variable` will not have such conversion.